# Nginx query param in location

Tags: nginx

I have a location block in my nginx server, if i access using `https://example.com/login/` display my alias folder value correctly, but if i use as follow: `https://example.com/login/?param1=value1`, i have a Error 400 bad request

```
location ~ /login/ {
    alias /var/www/app_one/dist/;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /var/www/app_one/dist/index.html;
  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `$uri$args` and `$uri$args/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try_files` is used to refer to physical files on the filesystem. With your configuration, when requesting `/login/?param1=value1`, nginx tries to find file `/var/www/app_one/dist/login/param1=value1`.

Depending on the actual contents of `param1` and `value1`, nginx might respond with `400 Bad request`, because some characters are not allowed when accessing files.